# lockf does not work, if running same program on a file

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

lockf() is not working correctly in below code:

If I run the below program:

```
user$ ./sellseat 3 & ./sellseat 3
```

the file which should be edited, can only be used one time. The second execution of sellseat has no effect, but both programs seems to be lock the file for write() at the same time.

If I execute the program one behind the other like this:

```
user$ ./sellseat 3
user$ ./sellseat 3
```

The lockf() will work fine and the file is locked and the other program execution has to wait and can lock the file too for its operation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* for F_TLOCK */
#include <errno.h>  /* for EAGAIN */

#define MAX_TRY 10
#define SEAT_SIZE 10

struct flight{
    int flight_number;
    int count_seat;
};

static struct flight* flight_pointer;

int lockWholeFile(int fd, int tries){

    int limit = (tries)?tries:MAX_TRY;

    int try;
    lseek(fd,0L,SEEK_SET);  /* set start of lock range */

    for (try = 0; try < limit; ++try){

        if (0 == lockf(fd, F_TLOCK, 0L) ){
            printf("Datei ist nun gesperrt\n");
            break; /* mission accomplished */
        }else{
            printf("Datei konnte nicht gesperrt werden\n");
            sleep(1);
        }

        if (errno != EAGAIN){
            break; /* mission impossible */
        }    
    }

    return errno;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd;
    int i;
    int eingabe = 0;

    struct flight flight_pointer;
    memset(&flight_pointer, 0, sizeof(struct flight) );        
    eingabe = atoi(argv[1]);

    if( (fd=open("adress.txt", O_RDWR))==-1 ) {
        perror("Fehler bei open()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if(eingabe < 0 || eingabe > 9){
        printf("Ungueltige Eingabe!\n");

        return 0;
    }            
    lseek(fd, eingabe*sizeof(struct flight), SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, &flight_pointer , sizeof(struct flight) );
    sleep(1);

    printf("Usage: sellseat %d\n", flight_pointer.flight_number);

    flight_pointer.count_seat = flight_pointer.count_seat-1;                    
    lockWholeFile(fd,10);

    sleep(5);

    lseek(fd, eingabe*sizeof(struct flight) , SEEK_SET);
    if( (write(fd, &flight_pointer , sizeof(struct flight) ) ) == -1 ) {

        perror("Fehler bei write");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }           
    lseek(fd, 0L , SEEK_SET);
    lockf(fd, F_ULOCK, sizeof(struct flight)*SEAT_SIZE );
    printf("Datei ist nun wieder frei!");    
    close(fd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think both executions are locking the file at the same time?

Comment: I tried it. The first execution printed "Datei is nun gesperrt", the second one printed "Datei konnte nicht gesperrt werden" once, then printed "Datei ist nun gesperrt"

Comment: Maybe check for `EACCES` and not just `EAGAIN`?

Comment: You shouldn't test `errno` after calling `printf`. You need to test it immediately after the error from `lockf`.

Answer (score 0):

The second process tried to lock the file, failed (possibly with `EACCES` and not `EAGAIN`, per the `lockf(3)` man page, or maybe `errno` was overwritten by another system call), and went to `sleep` for one second.  The first process finished, then the second one woke up, tried again, and succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your reply. I have found the problem in my program. 
If I change the function lockWholeFile() in something like this:

```
int lockWholeFile(int fd, int tries){

int limit = (tries)?tries:MAX_TRY;

int try;

printf("\n\n");


lseek(fd,0L,SEEK_SET);  /* set start of lock range */

for (try = 0; try < limit; ++try){

    if (0 == lockf(fd, F_TLOCK, 0L) ){

        if(errno == EACCES)
           printf("\nPermission Denied\n");
        else if(errno == EAGAIN)
           printf("\nResource temporarily unavailable\n");
        else
           printf("\nKeine Ahnung: %d \n",errno);


        printf("Datei ist nun gesperrt\n");
        break; /* mission accomplished */
    }else{
        printf("Datei konnte nicht gesperrt werden\n");
        sleep(1);
    }


    /*
    if (errno != EAGAIN){
        printf("\n errno: %d\n ",errno);

        break;
    }
    */


}

return errno;
}
```

errno is always 0 but that seems not to be the problem. I forgot to lock the file for the read function.

executing ./sellseat 3 & ./sellseat 3
Both programs read the same value i.e. 100 and decrease it by 1 and both write 99 back to file. The write was locked correct but the read wasnt.